# Safe string functions for native android development?

Tags: android, c, security, android-ndk

I was wondering - how 'safe' are the functions provided by android libraries when doing development of other native libraries on android? 
Are there things like Microsoft's strsafe.h or bstring? Or can those be ported over?

Comment: If you want to be safe, you should use C++ and std::string. But if we talk about C - then it is same as for any other C (gcc on Linux, or MSVC for Windows). Everything is up to you.

Comment: I was talking about specific C libraries that have been developed for 'safer' string manipulation. E.g. microsoft, when developing with visual studio, kind of requires the usage of safer alternatives provided to string functions instead of the regular ones. And this happens all over the windows world, even windows mobile OS is developed in this way. Is there something similar in the android world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually safe variants of unsafe functions you can use to ensure any manipulation problems are generally detected and dealt with before introducing difficult to detect bugs only noticed later on in execution. If I understand your question correctly, you may want to look at things like snprintf in place of printf, strncat instead of strcat, and using variants of malloc when creating character arrays that follow the 'succeed or die' convention.

I find these references helpful when coding in C for Android (I know the native library is lacking a bit).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Overview_of_functions

Using variants that require additional information, such as max buffer size or trigger easy to spot errors on failure is generally helpful to avoid subtle bugs that can be a hassle later on.